# Functions For One-Time Use

Tags: performance, code-formatting

In any language, is it better to use functions which are a bit long to write on the main function if you're only going to use it a few times? I heard that in Python, doing so will make the function faster. Is it also true in Javascript or in any other language?

Example:

```
function main(){
    blahblahblahblah1();
    blahblahblahblah2();
    blahblahblahblah3();

    blahblahblahblah1();
    blahblahblahblah2();
    blahblahblahblah3();
}
setInterval(main,1);
```

Is it better to group the code (blahblahblah) to make it look like this:

```
function blahblahblah(){
    blahblahblah1();
    blahblahblah2();
    blahblahblah3();
}
function main(){
    blahblahblah();
}
setInterval(main,1);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The performance impact of this decision is too small to measure in any language I'm aware of - the interpreter/compiler optimizes this away. The only cases where this may matter is if you're writing software for extremely constrained devices like embedded systems (but you wouldn't be doing that in Python or Javascript), or where you're writing software with extreme performance requirements like graphics engines for video games (but again, you wouldn't be using Python or Javascript for that).

Instead of optimizing for performance, I'd encourage you to optimize for readability, testability and bug resistance. Your second example is not equivalent to the first (it only executes the functions once, the first example executes them twice). Assuming you meant to have them equivalent, the second example is a little more readable, because the logic of executing the three functions is abstracted into a higher-level function.

Answer (score 1):

if you use a logic only once in your code, you shouldnt create a function - the compiler/interpreter will optimize the code anyway. if you plan to reuse the logic, then create a function - it makes the code smaller and better to maintain for you - even its minimal slower for the extra functionlookup and call, these are minimal performance effects...